# Set CORS headers in Tableau

Tags: apache, cors, tableau-api

We currently have tableau server accessible using "https://tableau.domain.com" and have embedded dashboards in our app accessible at "https://app.domain.com"

we also can access the app using "https://app.domain.io" but the embedded visuals are not working because of CORS settings.

how can i modify tableau settings to update the CORS headers and achieve this.

I see the below response in browser

```
Status 404
Version HTTP/1.1
Transferred 884 B (0 B size)
Referrer Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Thanks.